# Send Data from a Service to BroadcastReceiver of other Activity (Xamarin Android)

Tags: c#, android, service, xamarin, broadcastreceiver

I have a problem with sending `Location` from service to custom BroadcastReceiver.

This is my BroadcastReceiver.cs

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
class MyBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public static readonly string GRID_STARTED = "GRID_STARTED";
    public event EventHandler<OnLocationChangedEventArgs> mOnLocationChanged;
    private Location location;
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if (intent.Action == GRID_STARTED)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(context, "Grid Started", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            //location = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Location>(intent.GetStringExtra("location"));
            //mOnLocationChanged.Invoke(this, new OnLocationChangedEventArgs(location));
        }
    }
}
```

If I UNCOMMENT two lines in the upper code my app suddenly stops. I cannot tell you what is the error because, while developing Xamarin apps debugging is stopped by an internal error (I read about it on Xamarin Forums but couldn't find time to deal with it).

This is what I have done in service:

```
private void BroadcastStarted(Location location)
{
        Intent BroadcastIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MyBroadcastReceiver));
        BroadcastIntent.PutExtra("location",JsonConvert.SerializeObject(location));
        BroadcastIntent.SetAction(MyBroadcastReceiver.GRID_STARTED);
        BroadcastIntent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryDefault);
        SendBroadcast(BroadcastIntent);
}
```

I'm using Newtonsoft.Json for sending an objet.
Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**:

Ok, somehow I managed to reveal the error:

> Unable to find a constructor to use for type
>   Android.Location.Location. A class should either have a default
>   constructor,one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked
>   with JsonConstructor attribute.

**UPDATE**:

Whole service code:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace GoogleMaps
{
    public class OnLocationChangedEventArgs
    {
    Location location;

    public Location Location
    {
        get { return location; }
        set { location = value; }
    }

    public OnLocationChangedEventArgs(Location location)
    {
        this.location = location;
    }
}

[Service]
class MyService : Service
{
    private LocationManager locationManager = null;

    public MyService()
    {

    }

    private class MyLocationListener : Java.Lang.Object,ILocationListener
    {
        Location mLastLocation;
        public event EventHandler<OnLocationChangedEventArgs> onLoc;

        public MyLocationListener(String provider)
        {
            mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
        }

        public void OnLocationChanged(Location location)
        {
            try
            {
                mLastLocation.Set(location);
                onLoc.Invoke(this, new OnLocationChangedEventArgs(mLastLocation));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public void OnProviderDisabled(string provider)
        {

        }

        public void OnProviderEnabled(string provider)
        {

        }

        public void OnStatusChanged(string provider, [GeneratedEnum] Availability status, Bundle extras)
        {

        }
    }

    private MyLocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationListener("network");

    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }
    private void BroadcastStarted(Location location)
    {
        Intent BroadcastIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MyBroadcastReceiver));
        BroadcastIntent.PutExtra("location",JsonConvert.SerializeObject(location));
        BroadcastIntent.SetAction(MyBroadcastReceiver.GRID_STARTED);
        BroadcastIntent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryDefault);
        SendBroadcast(BroadcastIntent);
    }

    [return: GeneratedEnum]
    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, [GeneratedEnum] StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        try
        {
            base.OnCreate();
            InitializeLocationManager();

            locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NetworkProvider, 0, 0, locationListener);

            locationListener.onLoc += MyService_onLoc;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void MyService_onLoc(object sender, OnLocationChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        BroadcastStarted(e.Location);
    }

    public override void OnDestroy()
    {
        base.OnDestroy();
        locationManager.RemoveUpdates(locationListener);
    }

    private void InitializeLocationManager()
    {
        if (locationManager == null)
        {
            locationManager = (LocationManager)GetSystemService(LocationService);
        }
    }
}
}
```

**UPDATE**:

This is what I told in 6th comment:

```
 public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
 {
        if (intent.Action == GRID_STARTED)
        {
            try
            {
                Toast.MakeText(context, "Grid Started", ToastLength.Short).Show();

                a = new LatLng(intent.GetDoubleExtra("latitude",0),intent.GetDoubleExtra("longitude",0));
                mOnLocationChanged.Invoke(this, new OnLatLngChangedEventArgs(a)); // NULL EXCEPTION LINE
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(context, ex.Message, ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
        }
 }
```

Why is event handler mOnLocationChanged equal to null?
And service's part:

```
private void BroadcastStarted(Location location)
{
        Intent BroadcastIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MyBroadcastReceiver));
        BroadcastIntent.PutExtra("latitude",location.Latitude);
        BroadcastIntent.PutExtra("longitude", location.Longitude);
        BroadcastIntent.SetAction(MyBroadcastReceiver.GRID_STARTED);
        BroadcastIntent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryDefault);
        SendBroadcast(BroadcastIntent);
}
```

Comment: Where is location initialized in service?

Comment: I get location in LocationListener and then pass it by eventHandler to service

Comment: So LocationListener send "location" object to BroadcastStarted(Here) ? Can you post some code of it?

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: I think this will only work when location is changed, otherwise there will be no value in mLastLocation, since it is being set only when onLocationChange event fires. Try to simulate a location change by testing on device or emulator.

Comment: There is a location but I have read about a problem while json converting in this way in android. What I have also tried is that I put extra latitude and longitude to avoid object and json converting but in this case I get null exception when invoking event in broadcast receiver even though latitude and longitude really exsist (I used toast to verify this). Do you know any rule about invoking event in broadcast receiver?

Comment: you mean invoking onLocationChange() explicitly? like a method call? I never did that but there are times where I need that to do, where I cant wait for user to change location to get initial values. I will search for it and get back to you if I find anything.

Comment: No just simple invoking of event in OnReceive() method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Send data (not **object**) from **Service** (using SendBroadcast) to **BroadcastReceiver** (in MainActivity):*

[Android-java Gist here.](https://gist.github.com/talhahasanzia/c2edde310ab8ad4e1fd222c9aee98680) (100% working and tested code).

*C# equivalent Service Class code:*

(see import statements in a gist for required namespaces/classes)

```
[Service]
public class BackgroundService : Service
{
        private static LocationReceiver mTickReceiver;
    
        public BackgroundService()
        {
    
        }
    
        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent arg0)
        {
            return null;
        }
    
        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand (Android.Content.Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
        }
    
        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            registerReceiver();
        }
    
        public override void OnDestroy()
        {
            UnregisterReceiver(mTickReceiver);
            mTickReceiver = null;
        }
    
        private void registerReceiver()
        {
            mTickReceiver = new LocationReceiver();
    
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Android.Content.Intent.ActionTimeTick); // this will broadcast Intent every minute
            RegisterReceiver(mTickReceiver, filter);
        }
    
        // you can write this class in separate cs file
        
        [BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]
        
        [IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionTimeTick })]
        
        public class LocationReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
        {
            public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
                // sample data, you should get your location here,
                // one way is to implement location logic in this class
                double SampleLatitude=52.01566;
                double SampleLongitude=65.00487;

                // assuming above coordinates are from some location manager code
                Intent I = new Intent();
                i.SetAction("LocationData");
                i.PutExtra("Latitude", SampleLatitude);
                i.PutExtra("Longitude", SampleLongitude);
                // PREPARE BROADCAST FOR MAINACTIVITY
                SendBroadcast(i); // this broadcast will be received by mainactivity
  }
 }
}
```

*C# equivalent MainActivity Class code:*

(see import statements in a gist for required namespaces/classes)

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
        protected override Void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
            Intent i = new Intent(this, typeof(BackgroundService));
            StartService(i);
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("LocationData");
            RegisterReceiver(new MyBroadcastReceiver(), filter);
        }
    
        // public static variables of MainActivty can be accessed and manipulated in this class
        [BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]        
        [IntentFilter(new[] { "LocationData" })]
        class MyBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
        {
            public override Void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
                // GET BROADCAST FROM RECEIVER IN THE BACKGROUND SERVICE CLASS
                if (intent.GetAction() == "LocationData")
                {
                    double lat=intent.GetDoubleExtra("Latitude", 0);
                    double lng=intent.GetDoubleExtra("Longitude", 1);
        
                    String LocationDataFromService=lat+","+lng;
                    // REPLACE this with console.writeline
                    Log.d("LocationDataFromService",LocationDataFromService);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In `AndroidManifest.xml` declare the service as:

```
<service android:name=".BackgroundService">
</service>
```

It may still throw some errors. Hope this helps.

Comment: How can I get continuosly information from broadcastReceiver? At this point I'm getting information only one time.

Comment: I must remind you that this is the ciclus: MainActivity starts a service,service gets location every minute and periodically broadcasts the event with latitude and longitude as extras to broadcastReceiver, then broadcastReceiver is supposed to send location back to MainActivity which will update TextView with the given location. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Why do you need service? You need to run in background? Otherwise just implement onLocationChange() in MainActivity it will always (everytime) fire when location is changed. Whether you change location once or 10 times.

Comment: Yes, I need to get location in background.

Comment: Looks like we are stuck here, we still need location object for first invocation. I will get back to you when I find something.

Comment: Thanks Talha for that much effort. I have been asking this on many forums for two days and you are the only one who started conversation and is trying to find solution.

Comment: a is just a LatLng object that stores latitude and longitude sent from background service. mOnLocationChanged is declared in MainActivity. I think the problem is not between service and broadcastReceiver but between broadcastReceiver and MainActivity

Comment: Location has a constructor with one parameter - location. You can also do this `location = new Location(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Location>(intent.GetStringExtra("location")))`. To explain you this OnLocationChanged() event: when background service sends location to broadcastReceiver onLocationChanged() event should be trigerred and MainActivity should then receive that location - I'm using this to send data from broadcastReceiver to MainActivity.

Comment: Oh, so you need to send location data from Receiver, back to MainActivity?

Comment: Send data from a receiver in a service to MainActivity, code is in Android, but it works, and you should be able to understand it. [Gist here](https://gist.github.com/talhahasanzia/c2edde310ab8ad4e1fd222c9aee98680).

Comment: I'm getting some difficulties with rewriting this to c#. Can you show me how can I rewrite to c# just those parts in service and activity where BroadcastReceiver is being initialized? And please write link to answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Ok I dont have C# syntax checker so the code will be like not tested but I will post it.

Answer (score 3):

You can also implement interface in `MyBroadcastReceiver.cs`.I think its easier way.

Here is the code:

MyBroadcastReceiver.cs

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
class MyBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public interface LocationDataInterface
    {
        void OnLocationChanged(LatLng point);
    }

    public static readonly string GRID_STARTED = "GRID_STARTED";

    private LocationDataInterface mInterface;

    private LatLng a;
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if (intent.Action == GRID_STARTED)
        {
            try
            {
                // data you got from background service
                a = new LatLng(intent.GetDoubleExtra("latitude",0), intent.GetDoubleExtra("longitude",0));

                mInterface = (LocationDataInterface)context;
                mInterface.OnLocationChanged(a);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(context, ex.Message, ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.cs

```
public class MainActivity : Activity, MyBroadcastReceiver.LocationDataInterface
{
      ...
      public void OnLocationChanged(LatLng point)
      {
           // textview where you want to show location data
           locationText.Text += point.Latitude + "," + point.Longitude; 
           // things that you want to do with location point
      }      
}
```

If there are some problems with this approach, feel free to comment it.

Comment: This is nice solution, but I got Application type context instead of current activity context which is currently open.

Comment: @Mohsinkhan Cannot help because I don't see the code but, if you like solution, please upvote.